# Local Git LFS repo on multi-user machine

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have set up an LFS-enabled repository on a multi-user machine, so that others working on a project can share large, proprietary files that exceed our private GitLab instance's quota.  To avoid conflicts, we're having one person (me) keep the main copy in their home directory, and periodically use `git fetch` and `git merge` to merge in changes from their local clones.

The local clones are all working as expected.  They're created with `git clone /home/[MY USERNAME]/[REPO]`, and changes are committed locally without issue.

However, when I try to merge their changes, I get the following error.

```
$ git fetch [OTHER USERNAME] # the remotes are named after each user
# no problems

$ git merge [COMMIT]
Downloading [FILENAME] (96 MB)
Error downloading object: [FILENAME]: Smudge error: Error downloading [FILENAME] ([HASH]): batch request: missing protocol: ""
Errors logged to /home/[MY USERNAME]/[REPO]/.git/lfs/logs/[TIMESTAMP].log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: [FILENAME]: smudge filter lfs failed
```

Interestingly, after receiving the error, there are un-tracked copies of all the non-LFS-tracked files from the commit I tried to merge.

The log file doesn't include much extra information, except this environment information:

```
LocalWorkingDir=/home/[MY USERNAME]/[REPO]
LocalGitDir=/home/[MY USERNAME]/[REPO]/.git
LocalGitStorageDir=/home/[MY USERNAME]/[REPO]/.git
LocalMediaDir=/home/[MY USERNAME]/[REPO]/.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=/home/[MY USERNAME]/[REPO]/.git/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=/home/[MY USERNAME]/[REPO]/.git/lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
GIT_REFLOG_ACTION=merge aa5f82f
GIT_PREFIX=
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/libexec/git-core
```

Here is the output of `git config -l`

```
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
[MY USERNAME]=[MY NAME]
user.name=[MY NAME]
user.email=[MY EMAIL]
init.defaultbranch=main
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.[OTHER USERNAME].url=/home/[OTHER USERNAME]/[REPO]
remote.[OTHER USERNAME].fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/[OTHER USERNAME]/*
```

Am I configuring git-lfs incorrectly?  Is there an alternative approach that would avoid this problem?  We really do need everything hosted locally, as the files are proprietary.

Comment: What version of Git LFS are you using and what version of Git?

Comment: git version 2.31.1;
git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.16.2; git a5e65851)

Answer (score 1):

Git LFS is designed to work with a single primary remote, which is normally named `origin`.  As such, when you invoke `git merge`, Git LFS will look at that remote for the objects and try to download them.

However, in your case, you have multiple remotes, and so you need to use `git lfs fetch REMOTE BRANCH` before you merge.  Note that you should also, after performing the merge, run `git lfs fetch --all REMOTE`, since you'll need to make sure you downloaded all of the objects from the history for that particular branch; otherwise, you can end up with missing objects in the history if that person deletes their remote.

As you might have guessed, this is not the intended workflow for Git LFS, but it is nevertheless possible.